# Is there any in universe reason for the Trade Federation having their reactor run through the hangar bay?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In *TPM* Anakin simply flies his N-1 Starfighter into the hangar and accidentally sends a stray torpedo into the ship reactor core, obliterating the entire ship.  I know the real reason, but what's the in-universe reason?

We know the early Trade Federation ships were converted cargo ships, could it be that there was some benefit to having your reactor in the inner hangar?

Wookieepedia does seem to hint that the entire outer ring was one gigantic hangar bay in the earlier models, so possibly they were too cheap to armor seal it off.

This also brings up the question of radiation.  They can't let it contaminate cargo and random droids.  So we'll have to assume the case it's in is only very light radiation shielding.

Comment: Probably a combination of the conversion from cargo ships and the fact that no one would expect an attack from inside the hangar bay.

Comment: True, but wouldn't they worry about "industrial" accidents?

Comment: Makes it easier to swap the reactor core out every month.

Comment: My guess would be they have multiple hangars, and the distance to the core was quite far construction wise but not so far torpedo wise that are launched at very high speeds. Then very fast torpedo tore through the non armoured internal walls and reached the core.

Comment: That would be true but we see the actual reactor, it is in the back of the hanger.

Answer (score 7):

The Trade Federation Control Ships were not designed for combat - they were, in fact, originally designed as droid-controlled cargo carriers. It's entirely possible that the designers saw no need to shield or protect the core. As the ship was crewed by almost entirely droid workers, neither aesthetics or radiation shielding would be necessary.

Instead, it's likely the designers were targeting efficiency and ease of access. You could even speculate that the Trade Federation was cutting corners & production costs by leaving the core exposed as it was.

Comment: That seems very probable even likely.  Lucas is so lucky his fan base can find sense in any of his little plot devices.

Comment: -We should also take into account, though that some radiation shielding would be necessary, do to them receiving potential customers and delegations.  Though they probably didn't give any backup protocols, since all the living crew were in command module.  I know I'm being very nitpicky, but that's the nerd in me.

Comment: @LenieLenape Since, as you say, living crew didn't operate near the reactor (and customers and delegations probably didn't either, given Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon's proximity to the bridge at the beginning of Ep. 1) the decks and bulkheads probably provide sufficient shielding.

Comment: @KSmarts yes it seems your correct.

Comment: @KSmarts would not the droids who were stationed near the reactor or the cargo that was place there become radioactive?

Comment: I just pretend those episodes don't exist and only rewatch the first three films. :P